# Cycle hover on mouseout

Tags: jquery, html, cycle, jquery-cycle

I was wondering if someone knows how the Cycle plugin works.

```
jQuery(function($){
    $(".slides").cycle({
        fx:     'fade',
        speed:   450,
        timeout: 5,
        startingSlide: 0,
    }).cycle("pause");

    // Pause & play on hover
    $(".slideshow-block").mouseover(function() {
     $(this).find(".slides").addClass('active').cycle('resume');
    }).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).find(".slides").removeClass('active').cycle('pause');
});

});
```

Is there a way to restart the “slideshow” by fading to the first image on mouseout 
(instead of pausing)?

I found this code but it doesn't work for me.

```
$(this).find('.slides').removeClass('active').cycle('stop').cycle({
    startingSlide: 0
});
```

Here is my  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/baller/nwfy6dbv/)

Thanks in advance for any help with this!

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

Okay, ignore everything below. I found the solution on the FAQ page of the plugin.

The .cycle function can take an integer argument that sets the current slide to the index passed.

```
$(this).find(".slides").removeClass('active').cycle('pause').cycle(0);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WetNoodles/Ly0jxgz6/7/

---

It doesn't look like it's officially supported, however you can rebuild the cycle plugin in your mouse out event. (Also, I changed mouseout to mouseleave - it seemed to have more reliable results)

```
.mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).find(".slides").removeClass('active').cycle('pause');
    buildCycle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ly0jxgz6/2/

As an extra note, you can figure out which slide is currently being shown by jQuery's data function.

```
var currSlide = $('.slides').data('cycle.opts').currSlide
```

You could then use the 'prev' command to page to the first slide, but it looks like if you do that, the transition animation will be run for each one.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. I've tried the code but it isn't working for me. I've added a couple of slides but on mouseleave the        picture turns sometimes white. When I hover on the next slides the previous returns.   [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/baller/Ly0jxgz6/3/

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that happening occasionally, too. I'm not sure what a good approach would be, then. Sorry I couldn't be of more help. You might be able to make use of the currSlide if you can figure out how to prevent the animation or hide the cycler. (This gets you close) http://jsfiddle.net/WetNoodles/Ly0jxgz6/4/

Comment: @marvker I've discovered the actual solution after some more searching of the plugin's site and updated the answer accordingly. It's actually documented in the FAQ and demo sections, rather than the options/command docs page.

Comment: Thanks you helped me a lot. This is just what I was looking for. I have already implemented into my project. However it is not responsive but I am trying to figure it out.